# Magento 2: How to change the error/validation message in the customer login page?

Tags: magento2, customer, theme, template, login

I'm trying to override the error message that shows when a user inserts a wrong password/ wrong email.

> **You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled.**

[image: Error Message screenshot]

Where and how i can change it, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a CSV file at

```
app/design/frontend/{Vendorname}/{themename}/i18n/en_US.csv
```

and change the message as per you want.

```
"You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled.","Your custom message."
```

Let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: I successfully changed other phrases, that were not errors with this method, but i cannot change this error.

Comment: It worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**STEP : 1**
app/design/frontend/{Vendorname}/{themename}/i18n/en_US.csv

**STEP : 3**
Edit ev_US.csv

**STEP : 2**
"You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled.","custom message."