# Customized error message in the customer login page in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2.2.7

I am trying to change the error message "You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled." that appears when the user enters the wrong credentials in Magento2.

I have referred post: [Magento 2: How to change the error/validation message in the customer login page?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/246327/magento-2-how-to-change-the-error-validation-message-in-the-customer-login-page).

But I don't see any similar message in en-US file at app/design/frontend/{Vendorname}/{themename}/i18n/en_US.csv as mentioned in post's answer.I tried to add a message manually and tried to see if I can update the message as well.

Apart from that, I tried to override the Loginpost controller [[Magento 2 override the cutomer account loginpost controller](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/179636/magento-2-override-the-cutomer-account-loginpost-controller]), but it is not working as well.Not Sure, where I am going wrong. How can I change it?

[image]

Comment: Please check in parent theme which can be either luma or blank. If I am not wrong you will find this translation in Magento_Customer module. So check in this module as well.

Comment: I think I have to generate a file with a specific message. I don't see any file with this module